# Creating resultset based on column name defined in another table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

In Oracle database, I have a table DATA_DUMP_TABLE which has generic column names

```
id    column1     column2    column3   column4   column5  def_id
1      John         Doe        null     null        null      1
2      Tom          Baker      null     null        null      1
```

Then I have a metadata table COLUMN_DEF which defines the data column names. It could vary based on the definition id. Say in this case I just want to map the first 2 columns.

```
def_id   mapped_column     mapped_column_val`   
1         column1              First Name
1         column2               Last Name
```

The resultset I am expecting is based on the mapped_column_val from COLUMN_DEF table

So, in this case the resultset would look like this

```
id       First Name         Last Name
1          John              Doe
2          Tom               Baker
```

How do I achieve this in oracle, whether this could be done via SQL or I have to use advance packages? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This problem requires PL/SQL code and `execute immediate`.

Comment: Falling pretty squarely in the "Dynamic SQL" category here :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Works with sql server.

```
DECLARE @new_names     as nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @sql           as nvarchar(MAX)

SELECT @new_names = STRING_AGG('[' + MAPPED_COLUMN_VAL + ']', ',') FROM COLUMN_DEF

SET @sql =  'SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT t.ID, t.COLUMN_VALUES, t.DEF_ID, c.MAPPED_COLUMN_VAL FROM (
        SELECT ID, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_VALUES, DEF_ID 
        FROM 
            (SELECT * FROM DUMP_DATA) d
        UNPIVOT
            (
                COLUMN_VALUES FOR COLUMN_NAME IN
                    (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4, COLUMN5)
            ) unpvt
    ) AS t LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    COLUMN_DEF c ON t.COLUMN_NAME = c.MAPPED_COLUMN
) b
PIVOT
(
    MAX(COLUMN_VALUES) FOR MAPPED_COLUMN_VAL IN ( ' + @new_names + ' )
    --IN ([FIRST NAME], [LAST NAME])
) AS pivot_table;'

EXEC dbo.SP_EXECUTESQL @sql
```

Unpivot Will remove columns with `NULL` values.

INPUT:

```
ID  COLUMN1 COLUMN2 COLUMN3 COLUMN4 COLUMN5 DEF_ID
1   JOHN    DOE NULL    NULL    NULL    1
2   TOM BAKER   NULL    NULL    NULL    2

DEF_ID  MAPPED_COLUMN   MAPPED_COLUMN_VAL
1   COLUMN1 FIRST NAME
2   COLUMN2 LAST NAME
```

RESULT:

```
ID  DEF_ID  FIRST NAME  LAST NAME
1   1   JOHN    DOE
2   2   TOM BAKER
```

Comment: Too bad the OP uses Oracle, not MS SQL Server.

Comment: @Littlefoot did you test it? `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT` is supported by Oracle with the same sintax and `STRING_AGG` is standard sql. For sure there exists an equivalent for `SP_EXECUTESQL`

Comment: I don't have an Oracle server where test it. Thinking on installing one....

Comment: I didn't say that your query doesn't *work* (it probably does; I don't have MS SQL Sever to test it, and I don't know its syntax either). All RDBMS' are *similar*, more or less, but there are differences as well. Your code can't be copy/pasted into Oracle as it just won't work. One should *adjust* it first. It is similar to someone asking a question about Python, and you post a solution written in Pascal (for example, both have FOR loops so ... "tweak it a little bit and it'll work") - right, but I think that that's not the point.

Comment: @Littlefoot I don't think your example is adjusting the case. Oracle and SQL server both support standard SQL. Between Python and Pascal I don't believe there exists that similarity. I see your point, but I don't believe we have to be that rigorous when working with standards. I know part of my query is non standard for that reason I will upvote an standard SQL answer.

Comment: OK, no problem.

Comment: @SNR thanks for the solution, I had to replace the SQL code with Oracle

Comment: @pramodh which part had to replace?

Comment: STRING_AGG I put in LISTAGG and in the storedproc I did the sysrefcursor, I will add the code with your code

Comment: @pramodh as far as I read `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` is the equivalent to `sp_executesql`

Comment: I tryed to install oracle on a xubuntu, but oracle is not compatible with my version of xubuntu...

Comment: @pramodh you can post an answer yourself, with the code that you used.

Answer (score 1):

In general I think that this requires pl/sql and dynamic SQL as stated by @gordon-linoff

This is gets very close.

```
Create table temp_sgc1(id number, column1 Varchar2(20), column2 varchar2(20));
Insert into temp_sgc1 values(1 ,     'John'     ,    'Doe');
Insert into temp_sgc1 values(2 ,     'Tom'     ,    'Baker');



Create table temp_sgc2(def_id  number, mapped_column Varchar2(20), mapped_column_va
```

l

```
varchar2(20));
Insert into temp_sgc2 values(1,         'column1',              'First Name');
Insert into temp_sgc2 values(1,         'column2',              'Last Name');

Select * from 
(select * from temp_sgc2
pivot ( 
 max(mapped_column_val) for mapped_column in ( 'column1' column1, 'column2' column2 )
)
order by def_id)
union all
Select id,    column1,     column2
from temp_sgc1
```

;

RESULT:

```
    DEF_ID COLUMN1              COLUMN2
```

---

```
     1 First Name           Last Name           
     1 John                 Doe                 
     2 Tom                  Baker
```

Comment: Thanks, I wanted the First Name and Last Name to be the column names instead of the first row. Thank you for the swift response.